# init a list with vars flutter

Tags: list, flutter

I am trying to init a list of objects (it doesn't metter which object- they all give the same error), so for the example I am using Strings:

```
String str = 'str';
  String str2 = 'str2';
  List<String> strList = ["str", "str2"];
  List<String> strList2 = [str, str2];
  strList2.add(str);
```

strList is working fine, but I want to add objects from a server response, so I need to add vars, why does the strList2.add is telling me "he name of a constructor must match the name of the enclosing class." and "Try renaming one of the constructors."
I am new to flutter so its weird for me,

EDIT:
my test Class:

```
  class test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _testState createState() => _testState();
}

class _testState extends State<test> {

  String str = 'str';
  String str2 = 'str2';
  List<String> strList = ["str", "str2"];
  List<String> strList2 = [str, str2];
  strList2.add(str);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text('testClass'),
    );
  }
}
```

thanks!

Comment: It works for me in dartPad. I don't see anything wrong. Is this all your code ?

Comment: I use Android studio, this code is in my widget (in statefull class)

Comment: There's no problem with your code, I think you're using it incorrectly in your widget tree. Can you post the code where you're using it.

Comment: Just updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `add()` in the attributes definition. You need to use [initState()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html) like this :

```
class _testState extends State<test> {

  String str = 'str';
  String str2 = 'str2';
  List<String> strList = ["str", "str2"];
  List<String> strList2 = [str, str2];
  
   @override
   initState() {
      super.initState();
      strList2.add(str);
   }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text('testClass'),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code looks fine. The error message indicates that one of your class has a typo in it's constructor, hence the mismatch - for example:

```
class MySpecialWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MySpecialWidgetXXX({Key key) : super(key: key);    // <--- this produces the error you see

  @override
  _CreateMySpecialWidgetState createState() => _CreateMySpecialWidgetState();
}
```

If the error is **really on the .add line**, then my take is that you have a closing bracket problem somewhere maybe.

Comment: I posted my class above